# Why are absolute/fixed tab positionings for DocusignAPI not consistent?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the DocusignAPI SDK for node JS (v4.2.1) and am running into a problem positioning signHereTabs and dateSignedTabs. For consistency with other signing software (AdobeSign) I am trying to use absolute/fixed positioning with template roles. For example, I have a signHereTab and a dateSignedTab in the following tabs object

```
tabs:{
 signHereTabs:[{
  pageNumber: '1',
  documentId: '1',
  xPosition: '200',
  yPosition: '300',
 }],
 dateSignedTabs:[{
  pageNumber: '1',
  documentId: '1',
  xPosition: '300',
  yPosition: '300',
 }]
}
```

After defining the roles I update the template and do a getDocumentTabs() request to confirm that the xPosition and yPosition are as entered. I then create the envelope and send off the document. When I receive the document via email, the yPosition of the date and signature are different. Additionally, if I use the pixel locations that I have defined (and validated to be in the correct location) with AdobeSign, the fields sometimes line up on certain pages and sometimes do not.

Is this a bug with the DocusignAPI or SDK? Does this have something to do with the page size? Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to use anchorTags. These would anchor to text in the document. You can add hidden text (white on white) wherever you want the tab to be positions and not have to worry about x/y.
One reason this is happening BTW is the conversion to pdf as well as different resolutions etc. Using x/y coordinates is not the best way to positions tabs.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Ideally I would not use anchorTags as I'm trying to integrate it with PDF's used by another signing software and am trying to keep the PDF's consistent between the two. Do you know of any ways to avoid the pdf conversion problems or problems with different resolutions?

Comment: see here - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/tabs the third option is using pdf form fields. This only works if your pdf has these as standard fields and using the pdf form field option DocuSign will auto-generates the tabs for you in that case